# Draw distribution plots based on groups in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I would like to draw distribution plot for each group under column 'location'- plot of var1 for A,B and C under location. When I try the code below, it gives me one single distribution plot. I would like separate plots for each group. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

dataframe (file.csv):

```
location var1 var2
A        122   105
A        126   100
A        137   107
B        145   110
B        153   108
B        138   102
C        129   115
C        130   98
C        149   100
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt

dataframe = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
for level in dataframe['location'].unique():
    dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['location']==level]
    x = 'var1'
    sns.distplot(dataframe[x], kde=True, rug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an axis instance within the for loop and pass that to `distplot`. Also, using `groupby` is faster:

```
for location, data in df.groupby('location'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.kdeplot(data['var1'], ax=ax, label=location)
```